# bash add integer to string

Tags: bash, sed

I've been smashing my head against the wall for 2 hours already but can't get it work right.
Here is what I have:

- String, say 133, with "\r" at the end, so it is "133\r".
- Integer, which I want to add to the number from the string above.

I tried sed to remove "\r" with sed from that string and just (( )) with hope that math expression will truncate "\r" but still no success. Please, point me to my mistakes!

Thanks in advance!
Below is the file I read my string from and let's pretend that I'm forced to read this all the file (Screenshot from Notepad++).

[image]

Comment: Please include the code you actually tried.

Comment: Does the string end with an ASCII carriage return, or the two literal characters '\' and 'r'?

Comment: LF corresponds to \n, not \r !!! LF is for unix systems and \r is for dos, and corresponds to CR (see here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: @bendaizer, I'm totally confused then, cause when I try to sum string and int I'm getting error `)2yntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "\r"`

Comment: could you show your code ?

Comment: @bendaizer, unfortunately my code makes `curl` `get` request to the private repo, so even if I list it here nobody will be able to use it. Please, see accepted answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ a=$'133\r'
$ printf "%s" "$a" | od -c
0000000   1   3   3  \r
0000004
$ echo $((a+3))
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
$ echo $(( ${a%[[:space:]]} + 3 ))
136
```

Comment: This is the state of the art! Thanks you a lot for your help!

Comment: of course, the key os to avoid getting the CR into the string in the first place, not dealing with it after the fact. This is a quick `dos2unix` clone: `sed 's/\r$//' file | ...`

Answer (score 4):

You could use **awk**:

```
awk 'BEGIN { var="133\r"; print var+3; }'
```

outputs `136`

or you could use **bash** parameter expansion:

```
VAR="133\r"
VAR2=${VAR%\\r}
echo $VAR
```

outputs: `133`, so now that `VAR2` contains the number stripped of the `\r` you can add an integer to it.

Answer (score 3):

No need for `sed` just to remove a substring. `bash` can do it for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mystr="133\r"
myint=2

newstring=${mystr%\\r}               # Remove the substring "\r" from $mystr
myanswer=$(expr $newstring + $myint) # Add the two numbers
echo $myanswer                       # 135
```

Comment: unfortunately it spits out the following: `expr: non-integer argument`

Comment: See my comment in the question regarding what is actually at the end of your string.

Comment: Use the standard `$(( newstring + myint ))` in place of the `expr` command.

Comment: @chepner When I change `$(expr $newstring + $myint)` to `$(( newstring + myint ))` it says  `")2yntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "\r`

Comment: You have a literal carriage return, not a two-character sequence, at the end of the string. Use `${mystr%?}` as a simple standard way to remove it. If there is a chance that `mystr` ends with something other than a carriage return, you can use the `bash`-specific (although slated to be included in the standard, I believe) `${mystr%$'\r'}`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution

```
a="133\r"
b=${a/\\r/}
```

or even simpler

```
b=${a%\\r}
```

as it was suggested by [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)

Comment: Even simpler (and standard): `${a%\\r}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number using sed as

```
sed 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove \r with sed, don't forget to escape the \, this works for me :

```
echo "133\r" | sed 's/\\r//'
```

and outputs 133

EDIT :

as I said in my comment : "LF corresponds to \n, not \r !!! LF is for unix systems and \r is for dos, and corresponds to CR (see here:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)"

So you should try this instead :

```
echo "133\n" | sed 's/\\n//'
```

Comment: That outputs absolutely the same what it read from the file (please, find my screenshot in the edited post)